# Could a warlock use the One with Shadows warlock invocation to turn invisible, and then move while staying invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, movement, invisibility, eldritch-invocations

In the eldritch invocation “One with Shadows”, it is stated that the player is invisible in a dim location until an action or reaction is used. Since movement is not an action, could the player use just movement on a turn or outside of combat and still remain invisible?

Comment: Oh dear, my mistake, I read it over a few time and must have missed that entirely. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Movement breaks the invisibility of "One With Shadows".

The Eldritch Invocation "One With Shadows" states:

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible **until you move** or take an action or a reaction.

Emphasis mine.

If you move, whether on your turn or outside of combat, the invisibility ends.

Answer (score 3):

### Movement also ends One with shadows

From the description of the ability (emphasis mine)

> (...) to become invisible **until you move** or take an action or a reaction.

Answer (score 2):

## Movement ends One With Shadows explicitly

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible until you **move** or take an action or reaction.

Movement explicitly causes you to become visible.